# Знак препинания в предложении, содержащем как вопрос, так и ответ

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Какой знак препинания ставится в предложении, содержащем как вопрос, так и ответ на него? Например:
*Хотите быть счастливым – будьте им.*
Здесь и без вопросительного знака всё понятно. А как понять такой предложение?
*Любите Америку - чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.*
В русской классической литературе встречались предложения содержащие знак вопроса в середине предложения. Слово, следующее за ним начиналось со строчной буквы. Допустимо ли это в современном русском языке?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да всё же просто.

1. Если первое предложение — условие, то:

*"Любите Америку - чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон".*

Даже слово "тогда" перед чемоданом тут не нужно: и без него всё понятно.

2. Если первое предложение — вопрос, то:

Любите Америку? Чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон

Всё.

---

НО

Конечно, можно и так делать, если хочется:

1. Любите Америку? чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.
2. Любите Америку? — чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.

Но это, по Лопатину, "не соответствует современным пунктуационным нормам".

Comment: 1) Да не так всё  просто. "Любите (что?)  Америку -  (а именно что) чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон".  Это обособленный с помощью тире однородный ряд приложений. Как бы перечислены символы Америки, правда немного странные. Но так это предложение понял первый отвечающий, так могут понять и другие. Так что упрощать не надо. Структурное наречие дает Вам правильное понимание смысла сказанного. 2) Вопрос был вполне конкретный: можно ли ПО ПРАВИЛАМ ставить вопросительный знак. Вот и отвечать надо по Лопатину, по Розенталю, то есть по правилам. По правилам - нельзя, а Вы ставите.

Comment: И вывод. Всё. что Вами сказано верно, уже есть в других ответах. Всё остальное или сомнительно, или неверно.

Comment: Какой однородный ряд приложений? Это кто так поймёт? Сочетание "чемодан, вокзал, (такая-то страна)" - это сочетание фразеологическое, со значением "убирайся в такую-то страну". Т. е. "Любишь Америку --- вот и убирайся в неё". Фразеологизм широко известен, и ни с чем его не спутаешь. И поэтому Употребление слова "тогда" - факультативно, но необязательно. 

И вывод. То, что написано про приложения, - это глупость.

Comment: Я определяю синтаксис, он должен быть понятным. Даже если это фразеологизм (отнюдь не все его знают), предложение выглядит неясно и поэтому некорректно. Кроме того, на форуме не рекомендуется употреблять такие выражения, как "Вы в своём уме?", "это глупость" и т.д. На "ты" к участникам также не обращаются.  Вероятно, Вы плохо ознакомлены с правилами поведения на форуме.

Comment: Может, и скажете, но не здесь и не сейчас. Где-нибудь в другом месте. А здесь Вам, я надеюсь, модераторы объяснят,  как оформить Ваше личное мнение. А структура Вашего предложения  действительно некорректна, так как читающему неясно, куда ставить ударение. Он непременно споткнется о Ваш фразеологизм.

Comment: В четвёртых "Любишь Америку - чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон" - это максимум (хоть и в страшно уродливом синтаксическом сне) обобщающее слово-дополнение "Америку" и ряд однородных членов-дополнений при обобщающем слове (отношения "целое и часть"). А приложение, мой друг, это альтернативное название понятия. Город Москва (оно и город, и Москва). Птица зяблик (она и птица, и зяблик). А чемодан, простите, это не другое название Америки. И вокзал - это не альтернативное название Америки. И Вашингтон. Вот.

Comment: Вы меня будете учить грамматике?  Почитайте, например, Розенталя (тема - обобщающие слова при однородных членах): "Если однородные члены предложения носят характер ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ или уточнения, то вместо двоеточия после обобщающего слова может ставиться тире: Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.);  Ну чем Вам не Америка?

Comment: @ЛиХонг используйте, пожалуйста, местоимение вы, обращаясь к другим участникам, и не используйте слов типа _глупость_ при упоминании ответов или вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

Оба приведенных примера могут иметь **два варианта оформления**: 1) в виде сложного предложения (со значением условия) или 2) в виде двух простых предложения, первое из которых  вопросительное.

1) ХотИте быть счастливым — бУдьте им.

ЛЮбите Америку — тогда чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение (БСП) со значением **условия** (если хотите, если любите).  Во втором предложении для понимания смысла нужно дополнительно использовать структурное наречие ***тогда***.

В этом варианте важно правильно поставить логическое ударение на первом слове (оно выделено заглавной буквой)

2) Хотите быть счастливым?  Будьте им.

Любите Америку?  Тогда чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.

Этот вариант (с вопросительной интонацией) более экспрессивный и эмоциональный.

Согласно современным правилам, вопросительный знак в  середине предложения **не используется, кроме исключений.**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Примечание. Вопросительный знак может ставиться в вопросительном предложении после каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса: Что я — попугай? индейка?

Comment: К чему бы это — прописные почти в каждом слове? И уж если есть логика, то непонятно, чем объяснить разницу у пары чемоданов и вокзалов в двух примерах. И ещё. Выделение слов в каждой фразе, к тому же жирным и жирным курсивом, ведёт к обратному результату — нечитабельности.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за комментарий, но я ничего не поняла, кроме того, что Вам не нравится оформление. Я учту Ваши замечания, но в общем считаю, что это дело вкуса. Для меня, к примеру, нечитабельным является длинный текст, в котором автор не выделяет ничего, да еще при этом постоянно "перескакивает"  с темы на тему. К большому сожалению, я не поняла Вашего вопроса по содержанию ответа,  попробовала пересказать текст чуть подробнее. Смысл такой: вопросительный знак в середине предложения не ставится, но содержание предложения можно передать другими способами, не менее ясными и выразительными.

Comment: Я высказался лишь по форме: она сильно давила на содержание. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Знак ставится судя по интонации в конце.

*Хотите быть счастливым – будьте им.* || В конце интонация утвердительная. Да и в начале тоже не вопрос. Смысл такой:
*Если хотите быть счастливым – будьте им.*

[Если] *л**ю**бите Америку — [тогда] чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.* || В конце интонация утвердительная.

Если задаётся действительно вопрос, то его нужно оформлять отдельным предложением:
*Хотите быть счастливым? Будьте им.

Любите Америку? [Тогда] чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон.*

В правилах встречается только расчленение вопроса при однородных членах предложения:
*Кравцов ласково улыбался — его нетерпению? самомнению? гениальности?*
Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88

Было бы хорошо привести эти примеры из классической литературы с вопросом посередине.

Comment: *Любите Америку — чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон?* Вы вопроса не поняли.

Comment: Ну расшифруйте, что именно я не понял? Так корректней сказать про путешествие в Америку, где чемодан и вокзал присутствуют.

Comment: Александр предлагает вопросительный знак в середине (после "Америки"), часть после тире — вывод или следствие первой части: "Любите Америку(?) — (тогда) чемодан, вокзал, Вашингтон. А ещё он интересуется: можно ли без тире с "?" после "Америки" продолжить дальше со строчной.

Comment: Ну вы путаете меня: цитируете вопросительное предложение, а оказывается, что не понял, по-вашему, вопрос. Спрашивается не конкретно про то предложение, а в общем. Вот и говорю в конце, что в правилах встречается только расчленение вопроса.